# R libraries won't load after upgrading

Tags: r

I upgraded my R version today from 3.1 to 3.2. In doing so, I kept a copy of my original libraries in a separate folder. After installing version 3.2, I pasted the libraries in the libraries folder of R 3.2.

After doing so, I upgraded Bioconductor, and updated all its packages.

However, when I try to load some (not all) bioconductor packages right now in R, I get the following error:

`library(ballgown)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'XML', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Users/user/Library/R/3.2/library/XML/libs/XML.so':
  dlopen(/Users/user/Library/R/3.2/library/XML/libs/XML.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/R/3.2/library/XML/libs/XML.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ballgown’`

It looks like he's still looking for something in the older 3.1 version, but I deleted that folder.

Here is my library path in R:
`.libPaths()
[1] "/Users/user/Library/R/3.2/library"

[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library"`

Remarkably, when loading the same packages in RStudio, the error does not pop up. How can I still fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: @MrFlick this does not change anything.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and also this does not work.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I do get the same error message. I tried it for both the `ballgown`and `XML` packages.

Comment: This is a wild guess... I see a reference to libR - did you upgrade with a package system or compile yourself? I needed libR for another project, and had to add --enable-R-shlib to the compile options. If that's ok, then maybe (some of) the installed packages have a reference to the old version in 3.1 in them. If the 3.1 directory is empty, you could symlink 3.1 to 3.2?

Comment: Did you run `upgrade.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`? It is mandatory after an upgrade.

Comment: Eventually I uninstalled R completely and reinstalled all libraries, so the problem is fixed now, though in a rather inefficient manner.